# This is regarding Wave analytics Integration

Tags: einstein-analytics

can any one help me that is there any provision to work with Integration part & to connect with External systems using Wave?
Let me clarify that,i heard some ELT tools are there can any one give some names or any discription about this

Comment: Is it ELT or ETL (Extract Transform Load)? There are many ETL tools available eg. Informatica, Jitterbit etc.

Comment: Thanks for that ,i need a clarity that whether any ETL  tool is supporting Wave or not ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `ETL tools` used for `Integration` with `Salesforce Wave Analytics`. Few to name are `Informatica`, `Talend`, `Jitterbit` and so on.

Please find the below link for connection of Informatica to Salesforce Wave Analytics.

https://www.informatica.com/in/products/cloud-integration/connectivity/salesforce-wave-analytics-connector.html